# Rewriting an already compiled function at runtime

Tags: c

In a system with a precompiled binary similar to this:

```
int foo(int bar) {
 // do something wrong
  return ...;
}
```

Is there a method I can use to, during runtime, change the effect of calling that function to:

```
int foo(int bar) {
  return fixedFoo(bar);
}
```

Without changing other binaries? I.e. is there some memory hackery I can do to change the functionality of calling foo?

Sadly I cannot pre-patch the binary since the correct behaviour of foo is dependent on the result of runtime startup.

Comment: You could make foo a function pointer and then set foo to the routine you want after "runtime startup".

Comment: You can "pre-patch" the binary with a call to a fixed function that calls another function that does something dependent on the "runtime startup".

Comment: Which platform/architecture?

Comment: The general idea: write instructions (Windows: [WriteProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674(v=vs.85).aspx)) to push all registers (x86: `PUSHAL`), call `fixedFoo` (x86: `CALL`), pop all registers (x86: `POPAL`) to the address of `foo`.  Assuming there's enough space there, and remembering that this is architecture dependent and altogether horrible.

Comment: You might also be able to get away with using a straight `JMP` instead of messing around with `CALL`.  The code that you jump to would have to be sure to return to the correct place afterwards, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the source code, you could make foo a function pointer and then set foo to the routine you want after "runtime startup".

```
#include <stdio.h>

int (*foo)(int);

int bar(int a) { printf("bar %d\n", a); return 0; }
int baz(int a) { printf("baz %d\n", a); return 0; }

int main(void) {
        // do start up here
        foo = bar;
        foo(23);
        return 0;
}
```

prints

```
bar 23
```